# Ubuntu on Macbook 4,1 (pre-October 2008) Backlight Laptop Screen Issue

Tags: drivers, suspend, screen, macbook, backlight

I cannot get Ubuntu or Ubuntu-based systems to wake from sleep properly on a Macbook 4,1 pre-October 2008. The backlight for the laptop screen does not turn back on after waking and signal does not pass through the Mini-DVI port to my monitor either (monitor says no signal). I have tried to use the 01.org's drivers for my video card (Intel 965GM), but no luck. The installer (intel-linux-graphics-installer) will recognize the computer as Intel and find the server, but it will not find the driver for my computer (last step fails). The modprobe related fixes aren't working either. Backlight keys work up until after putting the computer to sleep.When I wake the computer, I have to shine a flashlight directly at the screen to see anything.

If anyone wants to help look through this huge mess from dmesg and have an idea, please help!!!:

http://pastebin.com/RZeVBMjJ